# How to prevent session time outs in a PHP environment on Windows

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have an app build in PHP 5.4.9 running on IIS7 ( Windows 2008 ).

Users log in and are timed out after a variable amount of time requiring repeated log ins.

In IIS, I have set the following to 240 minutes to mitigate the problem, but I still have users timing out well before the threshold.

```
Application Pools  > Advanced Settings > Idle Time Out
Session State > Time Out
```

Is there anything else I can try.

Comment: php sessions aren't integrated with IIS's as far as I know. check the php.ini settings (e.g. `phpinfo();` will show them) and see how things are set there.

Comment: In the “Session” section of your php.ini change `session.gc_maxlifetime` to be 14400 (that's 240 minutes).

Comment: @BennyHill If you're still here - I've set this setting up to 86400, and I still experience PHP session timeouts within stupid 20 minutes. I wonder if it's a bug in PHP CGI of my particular version.

Comment: @Vesper - I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. When it comes to web stuff I'm strictly a Linux/Apache guy... If I had to guess I'd say IIS is finding another ini file somewhere and not seeing your change to 86400.

Comment: @BennyHill No, I've ran `phpinfo()` to get the ini file, and the result reflects my settings. I've found another setting that can cause timeouts, and turned that off, now under testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing session files in the default folder, you might have another piece of software that is clearing temp files.  So move the session folder to somewhere else.